# iCloud Drive not uploading (Monterey)

Tags: icloud, storage, monterey

I am sorry sincerely for asking a question that seems to have been asked dozens of times before, but all the solutions I have found here and elsewhere do not work.

Over 250 GB of the hard drive on my MacBook Air M1 (Monterey) is occupied by iCloud Drive. Very few of the files in iCloud Drive are new — many of them are years old and are never accessed. However, occupying space they do, rather than heading off into the cloud.

I have tried lots of suggestions already, such as disabling and enabling iCloud Drive, restarting the "bird" process, trying the "Touch" command in Terminal, manually removing all files/folders with a "cloud" symbol to a portable hard drive and dragging them back across, etc. Some of the solutions involving Terminal, including a popular and successful one on this site, told me that "Operation not permitted" and went no further.

Nothing has thus far worked and I am very low on storage as a result.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Is you issue that the files are not uploading (are they missing on iCloud.com), or that your Mac is full and space is not free'd up?

Comment: They are not uploading. For instance, I have a folder of photographs (10GB) which are over two years old, which are occupying space on the hard drive and not uploading to iCloud. However, the folder (and dozens more) is stored in iCloud Drive > Desktop alongside many other folders which *are* on iCloud. The total stored localling amounts to 250GB.

Comment: Have you confirmed your iCloud storage isn't full? Is it just a folder with the image-files inside or is it stored in some special format (like in an iso, or some library file)?

Comment: There's 200GB available from the 2TB, so maybe that explains its reluctance to upload? Does it like to room in reserve? And it's dozens of folders with image-files inside (CR2 and PSD).

Comment: No, iCloud will fill right up to the edge (I think it gives you an almost full warning at 5GB free, but it will also fill those 5GB if you add data). When selecting iCloud Drive in Finder and going in list view (cmd+2), right-click in the header-section (Name, Size, Kind, ...) and check "iCloud Status". Make the column wide enough to show the text next to the icon - what does it say (Downloaded, Waiting to Update, ...) for the files that won't process?

Comment: There's a mix of Downloaded, Downloading (infuriating, since I haven't requested them downloaded nor opened them — thousands of jpegs — for months) and In iCloud. The "Remove Download" option does nothing, whether applied to one file or a hundred. I wish there was a way to search by iCloud Status and then "Remove Download" (that is, if the option did anything, which it does not).

Comment: Just so I understand the issue right. If you go to iCloud.com in your browser, are there files missing in "iCloud Drive" that are on your Mac or are all files present there?

Comment: It is / was a case of the files being in iCloud ... but also hanging around taking up space on my drive -- i.e. being "Downloaded" despite never accessing them. And also new files added to iCloud behaving the same way: uploading to the cloud but hanging around locally, too. I have tried every solution to no avail. However, this morning I removed my Photos library file, which I kept in iCloud Drive, and normal behaviour has returned. The Photos library has an "Ineligible" status in iCloud Drive and I am guessing was causing uploading to stall or blocking it somehow. That's my theory, anyway!